# stop animate outside of my window screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is working fine with left animate div cannot goes outside from left side but it is not working with right side div goes outside of window screen.

my html code:

```
<body>
   <div class="block"></div>
</body>
```

my css code:

```
div {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #abc;
   left: 50px;
   top:50px;
   width: 90px;
   height: 90px;
   margin: 5px;
}
```

my jquery code

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
var width = $(window).width();
var heigth = $(window).height();
if(e.keyCode == 37) { // left
    if (parseInt($('.block').css('left')) >= 50) {     
        $('.block').animate({left: '-=50'},"slow");
    }

}
else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    if (parseInt($('.block').css('left')) <= width) {     
        $(".block").animate({left: "+=50px"},'slow');

    }

}

});
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You've forgotten to reduce `width` by 50.

Comment: i try it but it is also not working

Comment: reduce 50 from width and also check if the result width is greater than 0 for left and less than window width for right and then animate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improve some code to @lukiffer's answer.

```
//...
else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    if (parseInt($('.block').css('left')) <= (width-150) ) {     
        $(".block").animate({left: "+=50px"},'slow');

    }

}
//...
```

Answer (score 4):

When comparing the current `left` value to window width, you're not adding the 50px that will be added as the result of the function, thus you will go outside the width of the window.

You should also account for the width of the `.block` element itself

```
//...
else if(e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    if ((parseInt($('.block').css('left')) + 50 + $('.block').width()) <= width) {     
        $(".block").animate({left: "+=50px"},'slow');

    }

}
//...
```